# Import GraphQL file in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, graphql-js

So I'm importing my schema generated by postgraphile, but it doesn't load rightly.

here is the type of ouptut:

```
definitions: Array(44) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ] ​ 
kind: "Document" ​ 
loc: Object { start: 0, end: 26188, source: {…} }
```

I tried every variation of the code to be able to load my query allUsers

```
<script setup>
import Schema from '@/graphql/schema.gql'

console.log('Query', Schema.valueOf('allUsers'))

const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(Query)
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The valueOf method is not appropriate for this purpose. A GraphQL schema document does not provide direct access to its queries, mutations, or subscriptions through a key-value pair access method.

First, ensure you have installed the graphql-tag package in your project:

```
npm install graphql-tag
```

Define your queries in schema.gql:

```
query AllUsers {
  allUsers {
    nodes {
      id
      name
      # other fields...
    }
  }
}
```

import and use the AllUsers query in your component:

```
<script setup>
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import { loader } from "graphql.macro";

const Schema = loader('@/graphql/schema.gql');

const { result } = useQuery({
  query: Schema.AllUsers
});

// Here, 'result' will contain your fetched data when available.
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: does not work I am using nuxt and for the moment my experience with it has been a nightmare. the valueof was when I tried every functions in prototype but it didn't work

my schema.gql is way much longer than just query allUsers. I don't use graphql.macro in my project just postgraphile (for the graphql middleware and connection to my postgreSQL) and nuxt apollo (for the requests to the postgraphile middleware). Postgraphile generates my schema.gql for me based on what's on my database that is generated by some files.

Comment: Dear alexander, That's sad that my answer doesn't help you. I just wanted to help.